# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: c#, wmi

code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
```

Above code throws the following exception please Help..i read in some article that this error are thrown due to WMI corruption?Is this the case?do i have to rebuild WMI or is there any alternate?or a better solution

Error:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32
>   errorCode) at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object
>   o) at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize() at
>   System.Management.ManagementScope.Connect() at
>   WebApplication3.lanusers.Button1_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\lanusers.aspx.cs:line
>   120 IpAddress192.168.1.55HostNamenkn-PC

Comment: I think this requires Admin access, have you tried running as admin???

Comment: Yes, i am running as administrator

Comment: Just to confirm, how is WebApplication3 running as an administrator? Is this being hosted in IIS?

Answer (score 6):

The Error code `0x80070005` is related to the WMI permissions.

> 0x8007xxx : Errors originating in the core operating system. WMI may
>   return this type of error because of an external failure, for example,
>   DCOM security failure.

In order to fix this error you must set the proper permissions in the client and server machines. Try these links

- [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Securing a Remote WMI Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Connecting to WMI Remotely Starting with Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa822854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi..i was able to access win32_process using the settings mentioned above,but trying to access win32_service gives me managemenet Excpetion

Comment: @smitha, What did you do to make it work? Thank in advance

Comment: i am facing `management Exception`...any one has idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enabling Anonymous access for the site in IIS?

Edit:

The error message clearly says what you need to do.

Use a separate limited account for the site if you want or enable anonymous access for the site in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Also Please allow the app "windows management instrumentation (wmi)" to communicate through windows firewall. Please refer this link for more info.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6229334e-d5ef-4016-9e7e-1c8718be8d43/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-eaccessdenied-in-vbnet?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 0):

The error `0x80070005` usually relates to permission denied to the cache files, so make sure they've the right permissions.

For example go to `/Users/Public/Application Data/Package Cache` folder (or other folder) and make sure that the folders and files there has the right permissions. Otherwise find out which temporary/cache files are causing the issue and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

tick checkbox of capabilities in appxmanifest in case of UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

U can use this code. It works to me

```
 void Close(string remoteComputer, string appName)
 {
     ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
     connectionOptions.Username = "USERNAME";
     connectionOptions.Password = "PASSWORD";
     connectionOptions.Authority = $"ntlmdomain:{Environment.MachineName}";

     ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{remoteComputer}\root\cimv2", connectionOptions);

     ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{appName}'");
     ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
     ManagementObjectCollection processes = search.Get();

     foreach (ManagementObject process in processes)
     {
         try
         {
             process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             //do what you want
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**