# How to Unregister a Scheduled Task to a User by the User?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I'm prototyping a PowerShell script that will run on a computer as SYSTEM when it's done, but currently I'm testing as Administrator. One of the things the script will do is potentially create scheduled tasks for other users, such as when one of them logs on. Specifically I want to have a "on first log on" scheduled task. So far I can create the scheduled task, and when I log in as the user it runs, but when it goes to the last line to unregister I get permission errors and it fails. Here's how I'm creating the scheduled task:

```
Clear-Host;

$currentIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$currentPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($currentIdentity);
$userName = 'JDOE';

Set-Content `
    -Path "C:\$userName-FirstLogOn.ps1" `
    -Value "
New-Item -Path 'C:\Users\$userName\Downloads\FirstLoggedOn.txt' -Force -Confirm:`$false > `$null;

'TEST' | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\$userName\Downloads\FirstLoggedOn.txt';

Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName '$userName - First Log On' -Confirm:`$false > `$null;

Read-Host;
    ".Trim();

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
            -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' `
            -Argument "-File C:\$userName-FirstLogOn.ps1";
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
            -UserId $currentPrincipal.Identity.Name `
            -RunLevel Highest;
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet;
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
            -AtLogOn `
            -User $userName;
$task = New-ScheduledTask `
            -Action $action `
            -Principal $principal `
            -Trigger $trigger `
            -Settings $settings;

$task.Author = $userName;

Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName "$userName - First Log On" `
    -InputObject $task `
    -User $userName > $null;
```

And the exception I'm getting is:

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask : Access is denied.
At C:\JDOE-FirstLogOn.ps1:5 char:1
+ Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'JDOE - First Log On' -Confirm: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_ScheduledT...TaskPath = "\"):Root/Microsoft/...T_ScheduledTask)
   [Unregister-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Unregister-ScheduledTask
```

I've made sure the user for the task is correct and I've even messed around with the task file's permissions and giving the user full access and/or ownership and I still get denied access errors. What should I be doing to get this working?

Comment: Does the same happen from Task Scheduler? Is PS running as Administrator? _by the same, I mean, deleting the task_

Comment: Yes, same thing from within Task Scheduler. If the user tries to delete the task from Task Scheduler, I just get an error that says: *The user account does not have permission to delete this task.* I **don't** think PS is running as Administrator, or at the very least the window that opens up does not say *Administrator:* in the header.

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure a Scheduled Task can delete itself, that might be the issue. Also, supposing a Task can delete itself, it will probably can't while it's still running (_by this I mean, there is a `Read-Host` at the end of your .ps1 hence why the task is never ending._)

Comment: Also, this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/17196322/15339544

Comment: It can. I do that in my cleaner10.io script at the end after the script was triggered by a scheduled task. It works there because it's processing as Administrator all the way through even after the computer restarts, while here I want to do it while running by a different user. The *Read-Host* was for me to be able to see the error before the window closed, won't be in the real script if I can get this fixed.

Comment: So, I think I got it to work as the current user, not sure if this would work as Administrator too,  I suppose it should. The task runs, creates the TEST file on Downloads and deletes the scheduled task after.. If you want I can share the changes I did.

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate that so I can see what the differences are. Thanks in advance! I may not reply tonight, have to deal with another sudden fire now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `$currentIdentity` and `$currentPrincipal` as I didn't see any problems using `$env:USERNAME` but re-add it if it fails for some reason.

```
$downloadsFolder = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path
$scriptDestination = Join-Path $downloadsFolder -ChildPath "$env:USERNAME - FirstLogOn.ps1"
$taskName = "$env:USERNAME - First Log On"

# Adding a Try {...} Catch {...} so if the Task runs but fails to delete itself,
# the error will be stored in a file.
@"
Try
{
    'TEST' | Out-File $downloadsFolder\FirstLoggedOn.txt -Force
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName '$taskName' -Confirm:`$false
}
Catch
{
    `$_ | Select-Object * | Out-File $downloadsFolder\TaskFailLog.txt
}
"@ | Out-File $scriptDestination

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' -Argument "-File `"$scriptDestination`""
# NOTE: The Access Denied Error was coming from here, -RunLevel Highest requires that the
#       current PS session is running with the Highest privileges.
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $env:USERNAME 
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn -User $env:USERNAME
$params = @{
    Action = $action
    Trigger = $trigger
    Settings = $settings
    Principal = $principal
}
$task = New-ScheduledTask @params
$params = @{
    TaskName = $taskName
    InputObject = $task
    User = $env:USERNAME
}
Register-ScheduledTask @params
```

Comment: Your script probably worked because you're affecting your own user where as I am trying to affect a different user. In the end I did figure it out. First, the principal was irrelevant so I removed it completely. Second, I added the user to the Administrators group, which allowed it to unregister the task on logon, and then at the end of the logon script I removed the user from the Administrators group. Works for what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c happy to help, and happy you could get your problem sorted out :)