# How can I reset an Active Directory user's password from ASP.Net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I am trying to do is to reset a user's password by filling in a form then click on the "Change Password" button.

So in my aspx page I have 3 `TextBoxes` One for the username, one for the password and one to confirm the password.

So basically it needs to locate the username which is entered in the text box then change the password according to what is typed in the other two text boxes.

So if I fill in the form and select "Change Password" I get the following error:

```
 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
 try
        {
            string strADPath = "LDAP";
            string strUsername = "user";
            string strPassword = "LDAPPassword";
            string userName = txtUserName.Text;
            string newPassword = txtNewPassword.Text;
            PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName);
            if (user == null)
            {
                error.Text = "User name not found in this domain.";
            }

            user.SetPassword(newPassword);
            error.Text = "Password for " + userName + "changed successfully.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // throw exception here
            error.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Not sure why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Please use `ex.ToString()` in the catch block and share the details obtained.

Comment: Hi, thanks,  Okay I see `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`  its a access denied error, however I am using Admin details to LDAP

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423920/12511801). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46300076/12511801) reminds me about permissions on "temp" folders and folders used by IIS. Please try and let us know.